# Why does FILTER_VALIDATE_URL consider this to be a valid URL?

Tags: php, validation, url, filter-var

For some reason that I don't understand, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL says the following URL is valid:

`http://ghjfgh`

Don't all valid URLs contain at least one period? I've never seen a TDL that didn't have one by definition. So why does PHP say it's valid?

Here's the code. You can quickly run it on [phpfiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org) for yourself:

```
<?php
$URL = "http://ghjfgh";

    if($URL != "" && !filter_var($URL, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        $error = "Please enter a valid URL";
    } else {
        $error = "All good";
    }

echo $error;
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It filters according to [RFC 2396](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html), and `http://ghjfgh` is valid according to that spec. An easy example would be `http://localhost` which is obviously valid (as @johnconde pointed out in the comments)